# Can I fit a 39Wh battery in my MacBook Air 2011 which states 35Wh?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm trying to change the battery in a [MacBook Air 11″ i7 1.8 GHz (July 2011) MD214LL/A](http://encyclopedia.macauthority.org/inventory/macbook-air-11-intel-core-i7-1-8-ghz-july-2011-md214lla/).

I found this [Runpower battery](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B012MHH880), which is 39Wh.

Yet when checking the specs mentioned above, the battery is a 35Wh.

If I change the battery to one with a higher Wh, will it have a negative impact or will it be ok?
Can I safely buy and install the new battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The battery you want to buy should be fine (in terms of the specs and compatibility). The 39 watt hours basically means that on a full charge it *should* last longer than a 35 watt hour battery (about 11.4% longer). Many after market MacBook batteries do usually offer a little more capacity in that regard.

As for the battery itself, I've never used that particular brand, so cannot vouch for its quality. However, since it seems to have a 5 star rating, it looks promising. As long as it offers a decent warranty (I can't read French, so can't tell), I'd buy it.

Comment: You can just change the domain from amazon.fr to amazon.com for the English version.

Comment: Update : Thanks for your answer. I did change the battery and it is now working like it used to. Cheers